# PHP- Codeigniter - return all input data trimmed

Tags: php, codeigniter, trim

I would like to trim every `input-data (get,post,cookie,session and so on)`.

I was trying building up an `hook` file but don't know when to make it run, since iwould like to pass all input data already trimmed to the controller, before the controller is executed.

Codeigniter documentantion says:

> pre_system

Called very early during system execution. Only the

> benchmark and hooks class have been loaded at this point. No routing
> or other processes have happened.

pre_controller

Called immediately

> prior to any of your controllers being called. All base classes,
> routing, and security checks have been done.
>
> post_controller_constructor

Called immediately after your controller

> is instantiated, but prior to any method calls happening.
>
> post_controller

Called immediately after your controller is fully

> executed.

which of those i have to use? pre_controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't use `pre_controller` for it. Use `pre_system` instead.

You want to do the modification of the input variables as early as possible otherwise [Codeigniters input class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html) will work against you (depends a bit on configuration, but `pre_system` is the safe way if you don't want to get code executed from within [*config.php* context](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Config.php#L130)).

For your recursive trim needs, this should do it: `array_walk_recursive(array(&$_SERVER, &$_COOKIE, &$_GET, &$_POST), 'trim');` as those input arrays only contain string values at their leaf-nodes. However take care with doing general things, it's often cause of side-effects, like with CI XSS filtering. Another alternative might be extending the input class if you're looking for a CI specific solution.

Comment: For your recursive trim needs, this should do it: `array_walk_recursive(array(&$_SERVER, &$_COOKIE, &$_GET, &$_POST), 'trim');` as those input arrays only contain string values at their leaf-nodes. However take care with doing general things, it's often cause of side-effects, like with CI XSS filtering. Another alternative might be extending the input class if you're looking for a CI specific solution.